# How to Insert in Oracle using java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am having CLOB column in Oracle Data Base , I want to insert String .

It works if I use setCharacterStream, but how to insert String by setBytes am getting exception.
Please help me.

```
String s = "Hello How are you Data for CLOB column";
ps.setCharacterStream(1, new StringReader(s), s.length());
ps.setByte(1,Byte.parseByte(s));
```

Exception Trace :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Hello How are you Data for CLOB column"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:447)
    at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:151)
    at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:108)
    at colb.test.InertClob.main(InertClob.java:24)
```

Comment: Here are two good examples: [Handling CLOBS made easy](http://rocksolutions.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/handling-clobs-made-easy-with-oracle-jdbc-10g/), and [Adding large object type to databaase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html).  I do *not* think you need the "setByte()" at all.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank you....such nice link I even didn't think about such nice pstmt.setString(1, str);....... ? If you can make this as answer.....

Comment: setString is wrong here. May work/ may not, you should store an array of bytes to a Blob field.

Comment: how do you and why do you say that may or may not work Please explain...and I didn't ask about BLOB.

Comment: Clob and blob here work identically.

Comment: @sunleo if you setString to insert blob/clob value into a batabase this is incorrect. May by you are lucky and it may work, but you cannot be sure that it will work next time. So, the correct way is to use setBytes. It will work, because this is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two good examples (with sample code, for select and insert):

- Handling CLOBS made easy:

http://rocksolutions.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/handling-clobs-made-easy-with-oracle-jdbc-10g/

- Adding large object type to databaase

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the [Java API DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String%29)

**Parses the string argument as a signed decimal byte. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits,**

Answer (score -1):

You should:

1. Turn the String to a byte array by calling s.getBytes() for example or any other.
2. Call setBytes method, not setByte
3. When retrieving from the database, don't forget how you got the bytes, in order to restore the String properly.